# How do I call HTML via AJAX - Elgg?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, elgg

I'm trying to call a view in Elgg via AJAX, but nothing works after **>>HERE<<**

```
$('.glyphicon-zoom-in').click(function(event) {

    $( '.full-image-view' ).css( "color", "red" ).append('<div>Hope this works</div>');

    // >>HERE<<

    var Ajax = require('elgg/Ajax');
    var ajax = new Ajax();

    ajax.view('albums/inline_full_image_view', {
        data: {
                guid: 123 // querystring
            },
        }).done(function (output, statusText, jqXHR) {
            if (jqXHR.AjaxData.status == -1) {
                return;
            }
            $('.full-image-view').append(output);
        });
    });
```

**Output** : Hope this works

What could I be getting wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

**UPDATE**

**inline_full_image_view.php**

```
<?php

    echo 'Hello World';
```

Comment: are you trying to add data inside a script tag using ajax?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Iceman. Right now I'm only trying to call the view via AJAX. The view is a PHP file which echoes a simple String. I added it in the question as an update. For now,  I'm not really interested in the data.

Comment: I posted a soln. in native JS. Does this work, if not I'll remove the answer!

Comment: If the soln. worked mark as accepted pls.

Comment: I'm trying it out @Iceman. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elgg uses requirejs. Try this:

```
requirejs(["elgg/Ajax"], function(Ajax) {
    var ajax = new Ajax();
    //rest of your code!!
});
```

Otherwise, using native JS.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', encodeURI('albums/inline_full_image_view'));
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
        alert('User\'s name is ' + xhr.responseText);
    }
    else {
        alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
    }
};
xhr.send();
```